# android - Sending a broadcast to MainActivity and then showing a TextView

Tags: java, android, view, broadcastreceiver, main-activity

I want to unhide a TextView once a method is called in another View file.
The TextView is in MainActivity.

For this, I am planning to send a broadcast from the View file to MainActivity, but it didn't work.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 0 : Define an action :

```
public static final String ACTION_SHOW_TEXT= "showText";
```

Step 1 : Create your Broadcast receiver in your MainActivity :

```
BroadcastReceiver  mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (myText != null) {
                myText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };
```

Step 2 : Add the register and unregister events in your MainActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
            .registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SHOW_TEXT));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Step 3 : Whenever you want to display your TextView, call from anywhere :

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.ACTION_SHOW_TEXT);
                        i.putExtra("success", true);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                                .sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

Comment: When I do: `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);`, I get LocalBroadcastManager cannot be applied towards com.simon.engine.com.FILE_WHERE_I_WANT_TO_DISPLAY_TEXTVIEW. How do I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)` takes a Context as parameter. Therefore, if you're in a frragment, call `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext())`

Comment: Great job, Nicolas! I have given you the maximum of 25 reputation points. Enjoy your weekend!