# How to active Broadcast Receiver only when APP is in background in android?

Tags: android

I am using Broadcast Receiver in my app which is active when app is open as well as app in close.what I want is to active this Broadcast Receiver only when app is open and also on specific activity.

here is my

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Check if the application is install or uninstall and display the message accordingly
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {
        // Application Install
        Log.e("Package Added:-", intent.getData().toString());

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {

        Log.e("Package Removed:-", intent.getData().toString());
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED")) {
        Log.e("Package Replaced:-", intent.getData().toString());
    }


}
```

Comment: See my answer on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36665760/4706693

Comment: Register the broadcast in onResume of your wanted activity, unregister it in onPause of the same activity. See the official doc for more info

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
@Override
protected void onPause () {

    // Unregister since the activity is not visible
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume () {
    super.onResume();

    // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver,
                                                             new IntentFilter(
                                                                     YourBroadcastReceiver.class
                                                                             .getSimpleName()));
}
```